# call html (php files) in silex

Tags: php, silex

how do you use html file views in Silex.

I am trying to use silex with some custom php code  where the controller method includes the views files.

Here is what I have: in my index.php

```
$app->get('/', function (Request $request) {    
    $homeController = new HomeController($request);
    $output = $homeController->show($request);
     return new Response($output);
});
$app->run();
```

And here is the show method of my controller:

```
    ob_start();
    include "view/start.html.php";
    include "view/header.html.php";
    include "view/contact.html.php";
    include "view/footer.html.php";
    include "view/end.html.php";
    return ob_end_clean();
```

Is there a way to make this work?

I do not want to move the logic of which views to show from the controller to index.php. And also I do not want to use twig for now.

And here is the error that I get:

> ```
> UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403:
> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
> ```

thanks

Comment: `return new Response($output);`?

Comment: What is not working? What's the problem? I can't understand.

Comment: @AI.G I added the error message that I get.

Comment: @u_mulder I do not understand your comment. Is it a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to the fact that [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) returns a boolean (success or failure). The function you're probably looking for is [`ob_get_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

```
ob_start();
include "view/start.html.php";
include "view/header.html.php";
include "view/contact.html.php";
include "view/footer.html.php";
include "view/end.html.php";
return ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error:

> *The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.*

One can safely assume that your problem is that one of your includes is failing. From the PHP manual regarding the `include`:

> *include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning*

So probably you're trying to include a non existent file or maybe one of those is generating an error.

On the development environment, you should make sure that your PHP errors are shown (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display))